# How to set proper route config in codeigniter framework

Tags: php, regex, codeigniter

we're using codeigniter framework to build application, but we're facing problem to configure '$route' to send correct request.

we just need to setup these route properly.

**How i access category:**

```
Category: http://localhost/codeigniter/category/'category-name'/

$route['category/(:any)'] = 'category/index/$1';
```

**Category Post List By Alphabet:**

```
Category Page by List: http://localhost/codeigniter/category/'category-name'/list/'A'/

$route['category/(:any)/lists/(:any)/'] = 'category/lists/$1';
```

**How i access pages:**

```
Page: http://localhost/codeigniter/page/'category-name'/'page-name'/

$route['page/(:any)'] = 'page/index/$1/$2';
```

we're using rotue something like that, maybe we have problem in it, please check these and let me know how to fix that.

In our codeingiter installation we are using 'codeigniter' dir, 'category' AND 'page' are controllers. in single quotes we are sending values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like

```
$route['page/(:any)/(:any)'] = 'page/index/$1/$2';
```

And

```
$route['category/(:any)/lists/(:any)/'] = 'category/lists/$1/$2';// But Iam not sure
$route['category/(:any)'] = 'category/index/$1';
```

Comment: with your code list working, but $route['category/(:any)/'] = 'category/index/$1'; is broken, category not working,

Comment: its working, is this okay, we can just pass $1 ? in controller we are just using segment to get values...

Comment: Yah Either you can get them via `uri` segments or may be you can from `get` params